# conditional probability of a statistic given a efficient statistic

Tags: conditional-probability

Suppose we have random samples $X = (X_1, ...,X_n), $ $X_i \sim iid f(x|\theta)$.  $T = T(X)$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

By the definition of sufficiency, we know that $f(x|T=t,\theta) = f(x|T=t)$. Does the following statement hold? $$f(w|T=t,\theta) = f(w|T=t),$$ where $w=W(X)$, a statistic of $X$.

Comment: Yes it holds, the probability distribution of $w$ depends on $\theta$ only through $x$...

Comment: @Daphna thank you. But, why?

Comment: Because $f(w)$ depends only on $x$. So it's only dependence on the parameter $\theta$ comes from $x$. If $x | T$ is not dependent on $\theta$, then $w(x) | T$ won't be either.